# sklearn train_test_split confusion

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I am getting an error running a code. What could be the possible error?

```
X = [['Item_Identifier', 'Item_Weight', 'Item_Fat_Content', 'Item_Visibility',
       'Item_Type', 'Item_MRP', 'Outlet_Identifier',
       'Outlet_Establishment_Year', 'Outlet_Size', 'Outlet_Location_Type',
       'Outlet_Type']]
y = ['Item_Outlet_Sales']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.80,test_size=0.20)
```

Error which I am getting :

```
ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.2 and train_size=0.8, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.
```

Comment: Is `X` actually like these or are these column names of a pandas dataframe???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are dealing with a `pandas data frame`, and your `X`, `y` as indicated by the lines :

```
X = [['Item_Identifier', 'Item_Weight', 'Item_Fat_Content', 'Item_Visibility', 'Item_Type', 'Item_MRP', 'Outlet_Identifier', 'Outlet_Establishment_Year', 'Outlet_Size', 'Outlet_Location_Type', 'Outlet_Type']]
y = ['Item_Outlet_Sales']
```

are only lists which are the indices of the real column names, this does not contain valid training data. If your data frame name is `df`, created by the lines, `df = Dataframe(your_data)`, you should try :

```
X = df[['Item_Identifier', 'Item_Weight', 'Item_Fat_Content', 'Item_Visibility', 'Item_Type', 'Item_MRP', 'Outlet_Identifier', 'Outlet_Establishment_Year', 'Outlet_Size', 'Outlet_Location_Type', 'Outlet_Type']]
y = df[['Item_Outlet_Sales']]
```

For extracting the `X`, `y` data.

Answer (score -1):

What is your X and y data actually ? are they really those strings ? or did you use the text as placeholder ?

You have a list of lists as X data. Thats why the code interprets it as if you only have one sample. That's why it tells you n_sample = 1 and when you split the training data will be empty. Remove the inner brackets in X and have a array/list like data structure for X. Then it should work.